# Download a file from Web when file name change every time

Tags: python

I have a task to downoad McAfee virus definition file daily from download site locally. The name of the file changes every day. The path to download site is "http://download.nai.com/products/licensed/superdat/english/intel/7612xdat.exe"
This ID 7612 will change every day for something different hence I can't hard code it. I have to find a way to either list file name before providing it as argument or etc.
On stackoverflow site I found someone's script which will work for me if someone could advice how to handle changing file name. 
Here is the script that I'm going to use:

```
def download(url):
    """Copy the contents of a file from a given URL
    to a local file.
    """
    import urllib
    webFile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    localFile = open(url.split('/')[-1], 'w')
    localFile.write(webFile.read())
    webFile.close()
    localFile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        try:
            download(sys.argv[1])
        except IOError:
            print 'Filename not found.'
    else:
        import os
        print 'usage: %s http://server.com/path/to/filename' % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

Could someone advice me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Aren't the file names sequential?

Comment: just craw this page http://download.nai.com/products/licensed/superdat/english/intel/, look for exe extention and download it

Comment: I don't know if file names are sequential.
-Hackaholic, I like the idea to craw the page, I could find the latest one and download. The problem is that I don't know how to list the content of that page using python, could you advice? thanks

Comment: Actually what I am looking is called "DAT package Installer" or 'XDAT file'
Does somebody know where I could download it from?
I am planning to use a script to do it. 
Thanks in advance
Note:
the one I tried before from this location did not work: Index of /140410/products/licensed/superdat/english/intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a two-step process. First scrape the index page looking for files. Second, grab the latest and download

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
import os
import shutil

# index page
pattern_files_url = "http://download.nai.com/products/licensed/superdat/english/intel"
# relative url references based here
pattern_files_base = '/'.join(pattern_files_url.split('/')[:-1])

# scrape the index page for latest file list
doc = lxml.html.parse(pattern_files_url)
pattern_files = [ref for ref in doc.xpath("//a/@href") if ref.endswith('xdat.exe')]
if pattern_files:
    pattern_files.sort()
    newest = pattern_files[-1]
    local_name = newest.split('/')[-1]
    # grab it if we don't already have it
    if not os.path.exists(local_name):
        url = pattern_files_base + '/' + newest
        print("downloading %s to %s" % (url, local_name))
        remote = urllib.urlopen(url)
        print dir(remote)
        with open(local_name, 'w') as local:
            shutil.copyfileobj(remote, local, length=65536)
```

Comment: -tdelany, I highly appreciate your help. It worked perfect for me.
Thanks